# Can't call the back button on a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with a view inside a navigation controller.  One of the buttons on this pops up a modal view.  I set my starting view as the delegate for the modal, and call the following:

```
- (void)dischargeSaveComplete:(dischargeView *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

It correctly dismisses the modal view, but it doesn't call the back button.  Do I need to do something else since it's inside a tab bar controller?

I tried set both to animation no as seen below, and it doesn't work either.

```
- (void)dischargeSaveComplete:(ehrxEncounterDischargeView *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Found the solution based on one of the answers, because I was in a tab bar controller, I had to call the popviewcontroller from the first view as seen below:

```
- (void)dischargeSaveComplete:(ehrxEncounterDischargeView *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) 
    {
        demoView *e = [self.parentViewController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        [e.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want 2 animations to follow one another, which is not allowed as you did it. You either have to cancel one of the animation or place popViewController inside the completion block for your first animation.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
];
```

Comment: Updated my question, I tried your suggestion, and it gave me an error about a wrong block pointer type.  Setting both to animation no didn't either.

Comment: I just changed the code, there was indeed an error with the return from the completion block. I just tried it and it worked like a charm !

Comment: It's still not working for me, but I think it has something to do with the fact that it's in a tab bar controller.  When I take the delegate situation out of it, and just try calling it on a button click with just the popViewControllerAnimated it doesn't work either.

Comment: Using your answer as a starting point I was able to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

u can try delay in performing second action

```
[self.navigationController performSelector:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:@"YES" afterDelay:1];
```

hope it works.. happy coding :)

Comment: Updated my question, I tried your suggestion, and it didn't work.  Setting both to animation no didn't either.